# How to read function f(x) from cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The following algorithm calculates the integral of the model function f (X) contained in the code. I want to change the function f = x ^ 2 + 3 to f = 2 * x + 2 or any other in Excel cell, not in code.

```
Public Function f(x) As Double

    f = x ^ 2 + 3

    End Function


Sub FunctionC()
'
' Całki Makro
'
'

Dim i, xp, xk, s, h As Double

xp = Range("g8").Value
xk = Range("g10").Value
s = 0
n = 100

h = (xk - xp) / n
i = 1

For i = 1 To n - 1
s = s + f(xp + i * h)
Next

s = (s + (0.5 * (f(xp) + f(xk)))) * h
MsgBox "Wynik " & s


Range("b6").Value = s


End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("G4").Formula`? I don't know what you're asking

Comment: Is it a particular function like a polynomial or any function?

Comment: any function i wrote in cell like : sin(x)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
In Cell `A2` your formula, depending on cell `A1`:

```
=A1^2+SIN(A1)+3
```

And in your VBA code:

```
Public Function f(x As Double) As Double
     [A1] = x
     f = [A2]
End Function
```

---

### Edit:

Here's another solution which does not depend on `A1`

A2:

```
x()^2+SIN(x())+3
```

Code:

```
Private x1 As Double

Public Function f(x As Double) As Double
    x1 = x
    f = Evaluate("=" & [A2])
End Function

Public Function x() As Double
    x = x1
End Function
```

---

### Edit 2:

You can actually get rid of the Parentheses for `x`:

Use the same code as above, just rename the `x` function to `xx`

In Excel, go to `Formulas` > `Name Manager` > `New`

Use `x` in name and `=xx()` in Refers to

Then You can use this formula in `A2`

```
x^2+SIN(x)+4
```

Comment: but i want to wrote in cell only: f = x ^ 2 + 3 or x ^ 2 + 3

Comment: You may need to do it in a new file for this to work. Also don't forget to change the `xx` return variable in the `xx` function. [link to file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08088406158839865510)